# How to classify a view by letter?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have tags (taxonomy terms) and created a tags pageview.

I want to sort my tags alphabetically and group them by letter of the alphabet.

How can I do this? Thank you

I want a single page. I don't want to filter the results.

**A :**

ring

accessory

**B :**

bracelet

cap

candle

...

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have found a possible solution but I need help. In my view I created a "Global: Custom text" field and I grouped this field in the format of the view.

It sounds really good. Now what TWIG code to put in the "Global: Custom text" field to extract the first letter of `{{ name }}` (which corresponds to the field "Taxonomy term: Name").

I tested the following code, but it doesn't work :

```
{{ '{{ name }}'|first }}
```

Comment: Isn't there a glossary view in core by default?

Comment: I never noticed the Glossary view before. Great share @leymannx

Comment: This is not really my question. I don't want to filter the results, I want to group them under a letter. Finally the answer is not suitable because it is necessary to create a term by letter.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you could arrive at this by having a hyerachrical vocabulary. Use the drag handles indent terms as below.

```
A
- term 1
- term 2

B
- term 3
- term 4
```

If you needed to list terms in a view, you could use the 'terms with depth' option.

No idea why someone has downvoted your question. It seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I updated my question. See below.